# Vue router linking external websites

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router

Please help. I have JSON file with bunch of url links. Some of them are internal and some of them are external.

JSON looks like this.

```
[
 {stuff..., "Url":"https://www.google.com/", stuff..},
 {stuff..., "Url":"/internal-link", stuff..}
]
```

And vue code looks like this.

```
<div class="mobile-link" v-for="link in json" :key="link.id">
  <router-link :to="link.Url">{{link.Name}}</router-link>
</div>
```

When internal link is passed to the `<router-link>` its okay, but when it passes external link, it will not redirect to the external website.

What is the best way to distinguish external links and pass it somehow through the `<router-link>` and redirect?

I would like to keep these links in one JSON.

Thanks for answers <3

Comment: you should probably just us an `a` tag for external links

Comment: you could add a boolean flag to each link object saying if it is external or not - alternatively, you could check to see if the link begins with `/` and naively say that signifies an internal link and everything else is an external link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do smth like:

```
[
 {stuff..., "URL":"https://www.google.com/", "external" : true},
 {stuff..., "URL":"/internal-link", "external": false}
]
```

And then in vue component

```
<div class="mobile-link" v-for="link in json" :key="link.id">
<a v-if="link.external" :href="link.url">{{ link.Name }]</a>
<router-link v-else :to="link.Url">{{link.Name}}</router-link>
</div>
```

If you can't edit your Array directly, use `map function` with regex `^(http|https)://`.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian ! 
Looks easy and works fine.
Much appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

As shown in your JSON, you could use a regex to determine if the URL is local or external.

So, something like

```
<a v-if="/https?:\/\//.test(link.Url)" href="link.Url"></a>
<router-link v-else :to="link.Url">{{link.Name}}</router-link>
```

Ofc, creating a component that encupsulates this condition will be cleaner. :D

Here is an interesting blog post on how to achieve it. It's talking about Nuxt.js but it's basically the same if you only want it for Vue only.
https://lihbr.com/blog/one-link-component-to-rule-them-all